# Flutter - Java calling C++ via MethodChannel

Tags: java, android, c++, flutter, java-native-interface

I am trying to create a Flutter application that will be utilizing MethodChannel to call some Java code using dart that will be calling a shared library written in C++.

I was able to compile a Java program that was linked to a C++ library using JNI and run it, However once I tried to import the files into Flutter, I run into errors that the path to the file.so Shared Library could not be found.

I am looking for help regarding how to configure Flutter and its Android files in order to be able to achieve this behaviour.

I will add the CMakeLists.txt I used in order to compile and link the .jar and .so.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7 FATAL_ERROR)

project(shared_library_java_cpp VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY NotNeeded)
set(JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY NotNeeded)
set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 NotNeeded)
set(JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH NotNeeded)

find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
find_package(Java REQUIRED)
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include(UseJava)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMALE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(JAR_NAME JavaCPP)
set(JAVA_SOURCE_DIRECTORY "/Users/user/Desktop/Temp/com/example/javacpplib")
set(JAVA_SOURCE_FILES ${JAVA_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/JavaCPP.java)
add_jar(${JAR_NAME} ${JAVA_SOURCE_FILES})

add_library(shared_library_java_cpp SHARED java_cpp.cpp java_cpp.def)
add_executable(java_cpp_exec java_cpp.cpp)

set_target_properties(shared_library_java_cpp PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER lib_java_cpp.h
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    SOVERSION 1
    OUTPUT_NAME "java_cpp"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "MacOS_ID"
)
```

In addition to run the code in intelliJ I used this method to load the shared library:

```
static {
        System.load("/Users/user/IdeaProjects/JavaCPP/src/lib_java_cpp.so");
    }
```

I am not sure of what library I should load when running in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to this problem.
After creating a .jar file and a .so file, I added that .so to the folder `android -> app -> src -> main -> jniLibs -> arm64-v8a`
I then added this line:

```
android {
...
    sourceSets {
        ...
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs += 'src/main/jniLibs'
    }
...
}
```

to the app/build.gradle file

and I added:

```
set(JNI_LIBS_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI})

add_library(lib_java_cpp
            SHARED
            IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib_java_cpp
            PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
            ${JNI_LIBS_DIR}/lib_java_cpp.so)

...
```

to the android/CMakeLists.txt file.

finally I called `System.loadLibrary("_java_cpp")` in MainActivity to load the desired library and to be able to call the Java functions from the jar that use the C++ library. (the lib is added automatically after call to find the correct shared object)